# How to properly select a code audit company?

Tags: code-review

How should I go about selecting a code auditing company?

Comment: The question should be a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to review the code as thoroughly as possible in-house.  Look at it yourself, and have colleagues do the same (provided they are competent and trustworthy to do so).

After that, you may consider showing some or all of it to external bodies that you are familiar with, like partner businesses that you cooperate with on projects - this obviously depends on the size and status of your business - a sole trader may struggle with this.

Then, selecting a code auditor will depend on circumstances.  A big part of this is dependent on whether you are looking for regulatory accreditation of any sort, like PCI-DSS - any regulator that requires code audit will usually have specific companies chosen to do this.

A good approach if you haven't had any code audited before, is to begin by having a small, low security project audited in the interests of assessing the auditor's practices and service, before giving them larger scale work.  Like choosing a tradesman, a lot comes down to establishing a working relationship, and assessing them on that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @owen said.  The main place you'll get security code auditor is penetration testing/security consultancy companies. Key things to look out for

1. Does the company have a good background with the specific language (and ideally framework) that you're using. Whilst some code review areas are generic you'll get best benefit from someone who knows/has experience with the language you'll use.
2. Ask the company what tools they use to do code reviews.  If they state that they do it purely manually or with in-house tools, I'd ask them some questions about how they'll get coverage in the time provided.  There are automated tools (e.g. Fortify, checkmarx, AppScan source) which, whilst they're definitely not perfect, make covering large code bases much easier.
3. On that note, if they do use automated tools, ask what the limitations of them are in their experience.  Some classes of issue (e.g. authorization flaws, 2nd Order XSS etc) are pretty difficult to find using automated tools.  If the company tell you they find everything, I'd be a little concerned about their experience.
4. Has the specific consultant that will be doing your review got experience in that language.  where you're looking at larger companies watch out for "bait and switch" where the person doing the pre-sales work is more senior and has the experience, but then the work is done by someone else.

Comment: Agreed on all points.